# Nix tutorial on installing in home directory

Tags: home-directory, nix

I am trying to follow this [tutorial](https://nixos.org/wiki/How_to_install_nix_in_home_%28on_another_distribution%29#Bootstrapping), in order to install the Nix package manager in my home directory instead of `/nix`.

I am doing the **PRoot** installation (see 2. in tutorial). At the end, the
tutorial proposes to be smart in *Building native packages* section, to be
able to run packages without PRoot:

> To run packages natively (without PRoot) they have to be build from source because all paths to the nix store are hard-coded. It is simple, really:
>
> mkdir $HOME/nix
>
> nix-channel --update
>
> env NIX_STORE_DIR=$HOME/nix nix-env -i nix
>
> And now your Nix store gets built up using the new paths. The built binaries can be run directly from there.

I did that, but I don't see how it frees me from PRoot. If I don't do the `/nix` mounting point with PRoot, nothing works (no `nix-env` executable,
I can't install new packages).

Should this `NIX_STORE_DIR` environment variable be put in my `.bashrc` ?

It seems I always need to run PRoot because `~/.nix-profile` points to
a `/nix/...` directory:

`.nix-profile -> /nix/var/nix/profiles/default`

There are more steps in the tutorial (5., 6.) - should I follow them ? It seems they apply only in case of using the manual installation (step 4.),
although it is not explicit.

Any help would be appreciated :)

Comment: After the last step, can you access `$HOME/nix/var/nix/profiles/default/nix-env` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For anyone stumbling on this old question: there is no currently supported way to install Nix without `root`. The above wiki was moved to https://nixos.wiki/wiki/Nix_Installation_Guide . It may well be out of date. `PRoot` could work, but even then, rebuilding the whole store at a different path is not a good idea, not the least because the binary caches won't help and you'll need to build *everything*.

I suggest trying Nix in a virtual machine or cloud server.

Comment: I just got it working as of Nix 2.0.4. It isn't too hard, just undocumented. [Code here](https://github.com/jefdaj/nix-no-root).

Answer (score 3):

Future people from Google, it's still unsupported but does work. [Script here](https://github.com/jefdaj/nix-no-root) that installs a couple dependencies, builds a temporary Nix, and uses that to install a proper version in your directory of choice.